# php mail() not sending headers when using phonegap and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, email, cordova, header

I have a very strange problem when sending emails. It's probably something very simple to fix but I can't find any answers online.

My ajax in my JQuery Mobile Phonegap application is (simplified):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mysite.com/ajax/app/email.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        email: $('#email').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('done!')
    }
});
```

The code in my email.php file is (again, simplified):

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$headers = 'From: MySite <admin@mysite.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: MySite <admin@mysite.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$msg = "Welcome to MySite!";
@mail($email, 'Hello', $msg, $headers);
```

The email comes through fine, but instead of being from admin@mysite.com it's from myaccount@web54.justhost.com. The email comes from the correct email address when I run the same ajax query from an HTML5 app stored on the same server as the email.php script.

Any ideas? I have whitelisted myserver + all subdomains - I can't think what else to do.

Comment: First try, `@mail($email, 'Hello', $msg, $headers, '-fadmin@mysite.com');` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick after I added the fifth parameter and set safe mode to Off to allow it (I have a terrible host that still uses safe mode...) Cheers pal

Comment: Excellent, I added it as an answer, so if you get a chance you can accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing your email address with the `-f` flag through the fifth parameter to [mail()](http://php.net/mail).  This will help the MTA know which address to use as the envelope sender.

See if this code works:

```
mail($email, 'Hello', $msg, $headers, '-fadmin@mysite.com');
```

Refer to the mail link above for information on PHP mail() function and also search `-f` on [The Exim Command Line](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch05.html) from the Exim Docs.

You will need to disable [safe_mode](http://php.net/safe_mode) if it is enabled in your PHP version.